# SQL nest tables

Tags: sql

Currently I have a table:

[image]

```
ItemCode  OldItem NewItem Usage
A                 B       3 
B         A       C       1 
C         B       D       5
D         C               1
E                         8

OutPut
ItemCode     Usage
D             10
E             8
```

Can you please help with SQL Query?  I have about 2000 Items that I need to add total usage based on the newItem link

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed. Also, [avoid pictures of code...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584)

Comment: How is `usage` calculated? What would the output be for A, B and D. How come C has 10 for usage? (remember to add the data in the question, not as an image)

Comment: D= C Usage + B Usage + A Usage because they are linked based on old parts

Comment: Whilst this question does have both sample data and expected result, it does lack any existing query, and it also lacks information on how d is linked to a,b,c - this seems critical but it isn't clear (to me at least).

Answer (score 0):

> D= C Usage + B Usage + A Usage because they are linked based on old
>   parts

I do not see how they "are linked" unless you are trying to indicate this is some form of hierarchy. I suspect you need to be more literal with how you decide to store old/new item values so that a hierarchy isn't involved. e.g.

```
ItemCode  OldItem NewItem Usage
A                 D       3 
B         A       D       1 
C         B       D       5
D         C       D       1
E                 E       8
```

In the meantime perhaps this will help:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN coalesce(OldItem,ItemCode) IN ('A', 'B', 'C','D') THEN 'D'
        ELSE ItemCode
    END AS ItemCode
    , SUM(Usage)
FROM yourtable t
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN coalesce(OldItem,ItemCode) IN ('A', 'B', 'C','D') THEN 'D'
        ELSE ItemCode
    END
```